# How do I extend my pre-existing javascript class without ability to touch class code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, let me please make it clear that I'm not good at all in jQuery, so I'm asking the gurus here for some help.

There is a large portion of JS code, which I want to extend in a way. Please also have in mind that I can't change anything in that portion. I can only insert another JS file in the HTML below the original, which will have to extend a method in the original JS file.

So, the original JS file (crippled as it's from a commercial community software) is this:

```
var memberlist = {};

(function($){

    memberlist = function($){
        var currentOptions = {
            //...
        },
        coreOptions = {},
        //...
        resultsCache = {};

        //-------------------------------------
        // PUBLIC METHODS   
        var init = function( url, defaultType ){
            //...
        },
        getOption = function(option){
            return currentOptions[ option ];
        },
        setOption = function( option, value ){
            currentOptions[ option ] = value;
        };

        //-------------------------------------
        // PRIVATE METHODS
        var toggleType = function(e)
        {
            //...
        },


        // A DOZEN OTHER METHODS HERE

        // THIS IS THE METHOD WHERE I NEED TO PLANT A DOZEN MORE IF CHECKS PREFERABLY IN THE BEGINNING OF THE METHOD
        doAdvancedSearch = function(e){
            //...
            if( !$("#f_inc_secondary").is(':checked') )
            {
                vals['f_inc_secondary'] = 0;
            }



            //...
        };

        //-------------------------------------
        // Make public methods public
        return {
            init: init,
            getOption: getOption,
            setOption: setOption
        };      
    }($);

}(jQuery));
```

Anyone kind enough to help me achieve this please?

Comment: Since that function is defined in a scope that isn't available to the outside, the only option you have is to literally modify the function by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to add other function calls / functionality within `doAdvancedSearch`? Just pass an array of function references, iterate through them and call them as you iterate:

```
doAdvancedSearch = function(e, otherFunctionalityArray){
    if( !$("#f_inc_secondary").is(':checked') )
    {
        vals['f_inc_secondary'] = 0;
    }

    $.each(otherFunctionalityArray, function(){
        this();
    });
};

// Function would be called by doAdvancedSearch(e, [func1, func2, func3...]);
```

You can use the above code by itself, so long as you can `doAdvancedSearch` privately. If you need something public:

```
// Create a private member in your initial variable definitions
var currentOptions = {
    //...
},
coreOptions = {},
//...
resultsCache = {},
additionalAdvancedSearchFunctions = [];
```

...

```
// Create another public method and make it public
addAdvancedSearch = function(newFunctions){
    this.additionalAdvancedSearchFunctions = newFunctions;
}
```

...

```
//Adjust your method call
doAdvancedSearch(e, this.additionalAdvancedSearchFunctions);
```

Keep in mind, we have no idea what logic you plan on doing in `doAdvancedSearch`. What logic you plan on doing within `doAdvancedSearch` is up to you.

P.S. This isn't really a jQuery `.extend()` scenario; More so, an extend your code scenario.

Comment: The doAdvancedSearch is triggered by a button being clicked. The event is defined in the init method of the file that I can't edit. So, I can't pass more parameters to its original call.

Comment: I'm curious how `doAdvancedSearch` is  triggered by a button being clicked because that method would need to be public. The method itself is not public, nor is there any public method that exposes `doAdvancedSearch` in some way.

Comment: I only need to add a dozen more checks similar to the one you see in the original code of doAdvanceSearch.

So, below, or above, or actually anywhere in the doAdvanced search I need to put this code:

    if( !$("#f_checkbox1").is(':checked') )
    {
        vals['f_checkbox1'] = 0;
    }

    if( !$("#f_checkbox2").is(':checked') )
    {
        vals['f_checkbox2'] = 0;
    }

    if( !$("#f_checkbox3").is(':checked') )
    {
        vals['f_checkbox3'] = 0;
    }

etc up until checkbox25

Comment: The method is called by another method. Anyway, JS files are visible when you have a direct URL to them, so I don't see it being a crime to point you to it... So here it is http://www.ibizaclub.gr/community/admin/js/acp.jquery.members.js

Line 46 calls method prepareAdvancedSearch(), which in turn defines the event (line 586) of a button being clicked to call doAdvancedSearch()

Comment: So, is it possible to achieve what I want without touching this file, but rather insert another JS file in the HTML code, and do what I want from there?

Comment: The only ways I can imagine this working is by [duck punching](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/). Also known as monkey patching, but I like this term better =]. I am not extremely familiar with how to use this technique, but it seems like it might meet your requirements. Essentially, you make a reference of the original function, then redefine the function, placing the reference in the redefined function. It's not a very clean way to code IMO, but sometimes requirements trump code cleanliness.

Comment: If you were looking to insert functionality at a specific point in `doAdvancedSearch`, you might be out of luck without editing the original JS file at least a little.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about this scenario, I don't believe duck punching would be a possible solution, since `doAdvancedSearch` is a private method.

Comment: Actually, besides the countless things that I tried that didn't work, one thing worked. Like I said, I can only insert another JS file below the point this JS is inserted in the HTML. So, I copy-pasted the contents of the original to my own, and hand written my changes in my own. So, this works, as mine is defined later in the code... But it's not elegant at all... Plus it'll be difficult to maintain, as for every new release the software gets, I'll have to check their code and apply any changes to my JS.

Comment: Very true. Sounds a bit like some extreme duck punching. _That_ sounds like it could be an olympic sport.

Comment: At that point, since you would need to now maintain that new file, you might as well have the Devs of that original file create the ability to inject additional checks in their class.

Comment: I don't understand why I can't re-define only the doAdvancedSearch function in my own file and change its code to suite my needs so that when the original file calls the function, it actually calls mine... But instead I have to copy/paste the WHOLE original file... That's totally beyond me...

Comment: Because `doAdvancedSearch` is a private method to the `memberlist` class. It is not publicly accessible, thus not malleable to sources outside of the `memberlist` class scope.

Comment: So, any effort to re-define it in my own JS file is futile... At least there is my last resort to copy/paste the whole file. Awful, but at least it works.

But is it absolutely the ONLY way? Or, are we missing something?

Comment: I don't believe so, purely for the fact that the method is private. The comment on your question would agree. We can always wait around to see if anyone else can think of something we haven't

Comment: Thank you Fillip for taking the time to take a look on this! :)

Comment: No problem! I've been doing a lot more classical JS recently, so its all really fresh in my mind.